# Duplicate object values while merging the JSON Objects arrays in Ansible

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I am trying to merge 2 JSON file Objects. But 2 of the objects are getting appended with the same value in both the JSON file.

Here Month & Year values are same in both JSON file like Month=1 & Year=2023, so its getting appended in the output JSON, how can i avoid this? The expected value in the output is Month=1 & Year=2023 and not Month=11 & Year=20232023.

***Input1***

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "item_value_01": "APPLICATION",
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "item_value_01": "HERBERT",
            "quantity": 1
        }
    ],
    "month": "1",
    "year": "2023"
}
```

***Input2***

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "item_value_01": "Test",
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "item_value_01": "Country",
            "quantity": 1
        }
    ],
    "month": "1",
    "year": "2023"
}
```

***Wrong Output***

```
{
        "data": [
            {
                "item_value_01": "APPLICATION",
                "quantity": 1
            },
            {
                "item_value_01": "HERBERT",
                "quantity": 1
            },
 
            {
                "item_value_01": "Test",
                "quantity": 1
            },
            {
                "item_value_01": "Country",
                "quantity": 1
            }
        ],
        "month": "11",
        "year": "20232023"
    }
```

***Expected Output***

```
{
        "data": [
            {
                "item_value_01": "APPLICATION",
                "quantity": 1
            },
            {
                "item_value_01": "HERBERT",
                "quantity": 1
            },
 
            {
                "item_value_01": "Test",
                "quantity": 1
            },
            {
                "item_value_01": "Country",
                "quantity": 1
            }
        ],
        "month": "1",
        "year": "2023"
    }
```

***Playbook***

```
- set_fact:
        list: "{{ list|default({})| 
                    combine({item: input1[item]|default([]) +
                                   input2[item]|default([])}, recursive=true) }}"
     loop: "{{ (input2.keys()|list + input1.keys()|list)|unique }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set *`list_merge='append'`* in the filter [*combine*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries)

```yaml
  result: "{{ [input1, input2]|combine(list_merge='append') }}"
```

gives the expected result

```yaml
  result:
    data:
    - item_value_01: APPLICATION
      quantity: 1
    - item_value_01: HERBERT
      quantity: 1
    - item_value_01: Test
      quantity: 1
    - item_value_01: Country
      quantity: 1
    month: '1'
    year: '2023'
```

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    input1:
      data:
      - item_value_01: APPLICATION
        quantity: 1
      - item_value_01: HERBERT
        quantity: 1
      month: '1'
      year: '2023'

    input2:
      data:
      - item_value_01: Test
        quantity: 1
      - item_value_01: Country
        quantity: 1
      month: '1'
      year: '2023'

    result: "{{ [input1, input2]|combine(list_merge='append') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: result
```